# Drill down Fusioncharts PHP class

Tags: fusioncharts

Can anyone tell me how do i create drill down fusioncharts using PHP class wherein all the data is present in one file and i can link the chart to the another chart present in that same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to create [LinkedCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/?FirstChart/LinkedCharts.html) (as per FusionCharts coined it). PHPClass does not allow you to create the data for the LinkedCharts. You would need to create the data using
your own PHP code and the pass the data to the chart.

Also, to change chart type, you would need to add JavaScript LinkedChart [configuration](http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/?JavaScript/JS_LinkedCharts.html#container).